# should i upgrade this model to inheritance?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I'm expanding my php and general coding knowledge by writing my own 'simple' CMS system.

My database structure follows:

```
USERS --< WEBSITES --< PAGES
```

In my logic, I have three classes, a `User`, `Website` and `Page` class. **NOT INHERITED**

The `User` class has all the attributes from the `USER TABLE` plus a `$_website` attribute,

The `Website` class has all the attributes of the `WEBSITE TABLE` plus an ARRAY of `Page` objects

The way I have decided to work this is, on page load, these classes will be created and filled with the database data.

So then in the html I can echo out results simply by calling the class like so:

```
$USER -> name;
$USER -> website -> get_pages();
$USER -> website -> pages[0] -> get_header();
```

---

I Realised that these classes could be inherited, so `Page` inherits `Website` and `Website` inherits `User`

But if I do it that way, then I'll instantiate the `Page` class like:

```
$PAGES = array(); 
$PAGES[] = new Page( $constructor_data_to_construct_user_website_and_page );
```

Now IF I do it this way, the object `$PAGES[0]` will have all the info to do with that page, and all the info to do with the Website (first parent),
and all the info to do with the User ( second parent )

If i then create another `Page`, i'm just **copying** the same `User` and `Website` details ***Yes***?

So if i were to `var_dump $PAGES[0]` id get ALL the info to do with `USER,` `WEBSITE` and `PAGE`

If i were to `var_dump $PAGES[1]` id get ALL THE SAME information for `USERS` AND `WEBSITE`, but just the different `Page` data.

*So inheritance, is causing unnecessary copying of the User and Website objects*

Because I could essentially do:

```
$PAGES[0] -> username // username is a property of the Users class
$PAGES[1] -> username
```

both would return EXACTLY the same value.

surely this is bad because data is being unnecessarily copied!

***Is This Correct?***

Or is this question a load of rubbish and this isn't the kind of situation `inheritance` is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly the sort of situation where you *must not* use inheritance.

**Inheritance is meant to model an `IS-A` relationship**. Typical example: a `Student` is a type of `Person`, so `Student` inherits from `Person`.

**Inheritance is not, *not*, *NOT* meant to model a `HAS-A` relationship**. Typical example: a `Car` has an `Engine`, but `Car` *is not* a type of `Engine`.

When we have a `HAS-A` relationship (e.g. a User has Website) you should almost in all cases use composition instead of inheritance:

### Bad

```
class Website extends User {}
```

### Good

```
class Website {
    private $users;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is used when a subclass is needed that is basically a specific type of the parent class.  So for example a hierarchy of Animal -> Mammal -> Horse would be a reasonable inheritance hierarchy since horses are specific types of mammals and mammals are specific types of animals.

In your case I would not use inheritance.  A website contains pages but pages are not an extension of a website per-se, and a user is a totally different thing altogether.  When making a decision you usually use "is-a" vs. "has-a", as in

a Page is a Website vs. a Website has a Page

In this case I think the latter (has-a) is more descriptive.  If the phrase "is-a" fits better then it may be a good candidate for inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not correct. You should only inherit when one is a subtype of another one.

For instance, if you were representing people, you might have a relation like Manager inherits Employee, because a Manager is a specific type of Employee. A Website is not a specific type of User, so inheritance would not make sense.

What you instead are looking for is a simple has-a relationship (aggregation), since a website may have many pages, and a user may have many websites.

Answer (score 0):

if you declare website and user fields as "static" in their classes:

```
class Website extends User {
    protected static $_xxx = '123';
}

class User {
    protected static $_username = 'Fred';
}
```

then they will not be copied, but will be Exactly the same value.

But this is wrong do inheritance in that palce - its tied objects, but not inherited. So you must dont use inheritance in this case - parent class must be superset of child class.